# Alignment of data

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi using the following coding i am having a small issue.
if you go to my page http://freebetoffersonline.com/bet-calc.php and click any bet type and then any number of winners, you will see the calculator that appears is not aligned properly and overlaps my slider

I have identified it (i think) to be the this part of the below coding

```
.calculator {
position:relative;
background-color:#fff;
width: 880px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin-top: 180px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

But when i then reduce the width, it all comes into the alignment here i want it to be, however the bottom 2 boxes (Total Return and Total Profit) are no longer side by side and one drops down a full level.

```
RR
```

So instead of looking like the 2 R's above

```
R
 R
```

It looks like these 2 R's above

```
/* BET CALCLATOR */

.bidlist {
position:absolute;
background-color:#fff;
width: 560px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
}

.bidlist div.row {
float: left;
text-align:center;
width: 25%;
}


.calculator {
position:relative;
background-color:#fff;
width: 880px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin-top: 180px;
padding: 10px;
}


.betbutton{
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-style:solid;
border-color:#FDF382 #FFEE30 #ffea00 #FDEE42;
border-width:3px 4px 4px 3px;
width:9em;
height:2em;
background:#128F01;
line-height:2;
text-align:center;
font-weight:900;
padding: 5px;
width: 93%;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Aller, Arial;
font-size: 14px;
}

.betbutton:hover{
border-color: #FDF382 #FFEE30 #ffea00 #FDEE42;
border-width:4px 3px 3px 4px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ffea00;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding: 5px;
}

.unitstake {
    border:2px solid #bbbbbb;
text-align: center;
 height:80px;
 z-index:15;
 margin: 0 40% 0 40%;
}

.unitstake div.head{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.oddselection{
    /*border:2px solid #bbbbbb;*/
text-align: center;
 z-index:15;
 margin: 0 30% 0 30%;

}

.oddselection div.head{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}


.oddselection div.left{
border:2px solid #bbbbbb;
float: left;
width: 33%;
}

.oddselection div.left div.head{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.oddselection div.left div.row{
height: 30px;
}
.oddselection div.left div.row1{
height: 60px;
}

.oddselection div.right{
border:2px solid #bbbbbb;
float:right;
width: 63%;
}

.oddselection div.right div.head{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}


.oddselection div.right div.row{
height: 30px;
}

.oddselection div.right div.row1{
height: 60px;
}



.betamountinput{
border:1px solid #456879;
border-radius:3px;
height: 22px;
width: 100px;
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}



.betoddinput{
border:1px solid #456879;
border-radius:3px;
height: 20px;
width: 50px;
padding: 0 0 0 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-bottom: 1px;
}


.calculate{
text-align: center;
 z-index:15;
 margin: 0 30% 0 30%;

}

.btnCalculate {
height: 35px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-family: Aller, Arial;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #0C5A01;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
}

.btnCalculate:hover {
border-color: #FDF382 #FFEE30 #ffea00 #FDEE42;
border-width:4px 3px 3px 4px;
}


.result1{
    /*border:2px solid #bbbbbb;*/
text-align: center;
 height:80px;
 z-index:15;
 margin: 0 30% 0 30%;

}

.result1 div.head{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}


.result1 div.left{
border:2px solid #bbbbbb;
float: left;
width: 48%;
}


.result1 div.left div.head{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.result1 div.right{
border:2px solid #bbbbbb;
float:right;
width: 48%;
}

.result1 div.right div.head{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.result2{
    /*border:2px solid #bbbbbb;*/
text-align: center;
 z-index:15;
  height:80px;
 margin: 0 20% 0 20%;

}

.result2 div.head{

float: left;
width: 100%;
}


.result2 div.left{
border:2px solid #bbbbbb;
float: left;
width: 49%;
}

.result2 div.left div.head{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.result2 div.right{
border:2px solid #bbbbbb;
float:right;
width: 49%;
}


.result2 div.right div.head{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.heading1 {
margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
color: #343434;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Orienta', sans-serif;
}


.heading2 {
margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
color: #343434;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
font-family: Aller, Arial;
}

.heading3 {
margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
color: #343434;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Aller, Arial;
}



.noofwinners {
position:relative;
background-color:#fff;
width: 560px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin-top: 180px;
padding: 10px;
}


.winnerbutton{
     margin: 0 30% 0 30%;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-style:solid;
border-color:#FDF382 #FFEE30 #ffea00 #FDEE42;
border-width:3px 4px 4px 3px;
height:2em;
background:#0C5A01;
line-height:2;
text-align:center;
font-weight:900;
padding: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Aller, Arial;
font-size: 14px;
}

.winnerbutton:hover{
border-color: #FDF382 #FFEE30 #ffea00 #FDEE42;
border-width:4px 3px 3px 4px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ffea00;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I went to your site but couldn't find the part you're talking about

Comment: hi it is at http://freebetoffersonline.com/bet-calc.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with the code. Here's the last screen shot I have

[image: Bet Calc new]

Obviously if you want the right side slider then you need to compromise some width and height of the calculator.

```
.calculator {
position: relative;
background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin-top: 180px;
padding: 10px;}
```

This was the css changed width to 100%.

Then reduce the widths of the other div ie the total bet and other. Since a lot of hardcoding is there applying percentage is not so easy now. Try you ll get an out put but you might compromise the width of the calculator section and its content.

**These are the other edits**

```
.result2 div.right {
border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
float: right;
width: 48%;
}



.result1 div.left {
border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
float: left;
width: 48%;
height: 100%;
}


.result1 div.right {
border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 48%;
}
```

Look at this pic . Is it some thing like this you are looking for ?

[image: New bet]

Comment: Many thanks for you answer - i have done what you said and changed it to 100% but no joy i am afraid - did you change anything else to it?

Comment: Wait Ill share a complete css :)

Comment: Are you changing in the live ?

Comment: what do you mean sorry - changing on the live?

Comment: I dont know but when i firbugged it and changes some styles it prevailed the next time i opened it . I thot u changed some thing over there ie the link http://freebetoffersonline.com/bet-calc.php So got confused and asked

Comment: i have tried to make changes for what you said but i must be very confused - could i possibly email u my css file?

Comment: i would be extremely grateful to you if this could be the case

Comment: Check the Image i added Is it some thing you want at that portion ?

Comment: Yes that is it - ideally number of bets box  - all the words on one line or the Total Stake to drop to 2 - but i am sure that is just simply a case of changing the font size???

But what you have done is brilliant and is what i am looking for yes!

Comment: Please try adding the edited css i gave u and replace them with the old one. If not working then try marking it !important :) let me know when you have edited. replace .result2 div.right , .result1 div.right, .result1 div.left .. with the styles i gave .. I edited the styles as the media option was coming because of firebug i guess.

Comment: Yes copy that over and replace them in line and replace them with the classses you wrote at around line 975 to ... in your css

Comment: Mate - you are a GENIUS!!!!!  have applied what you said and then changed the font size and line height to the other 2 boxes and all looks perfect with the alignment now

Comment: :) :) Not a genius though :) surely a developer but :D Accept the answer Plz :P